# Copying a string with ARM/C

Tags: c, string, assembly, arm

so I'm trying to learn ARM, and am practicing by taking a character array pointer from C, copying that string, and returning a pointer to a different character array. I've written up this code (commented with what I assume I happening):

```
    .global copy                    @Let the linker know what's going on

copy:                           @Start
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}      @Push stuff onto stack
    mov r6, a1                  @Put the pointer to the original string in r6
    bl length                   @Get the length of the string
    mov a1, r4                  @Put length into the input parameter
    bl malloc                   @Allocate enough memory for our new string
    mov r9, a1                  @Move the first memory location to r9

loop:                           @Loop to copy string
    ldrb r8, [r6], #1           @Load first character from string and move pointer
    strb r8, [a1], #1           @Store character in new string and move character
    subs r4, r4, #1             @Subtract 1 from length
    bne loop                    @Stop looping if string is done
    mov a1, r9                  @Move the start of the new string to the return value
    b ending                    @Go to the ending


length:                         @Length function
    mov r4, #0                  @counter set to 0
countLoop: 
    ldrb r5, [r6], #1           @Load first character
    cmp r5, #0                  @Check for null character
    add r4, r4, #1              @Add 1 to the length
    bne countLoop               @Loop if we're not at the end
    mov pc, lr                  @Return the program

ending:
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}      @Pop stuff off the stack
.end
```

With this C driver:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
extern char * copy( char str[] ) ; /* declare the assembly routine */
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   char str[] = "abcd" ;
   char * result;
   result = copy( str ) ; /* call the assembly language routine */
   printf("Will this work? %s", result);
   exit(0);
}
```

However I keeping getting the result (null). Obviously something is not correct in my thinking, but I don't know what it is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your C code contains a type error. `printf` `%s` takes a `char *`, but you're passing an `int`.

Comment: Changing that gives me an output of nothing. I think my pointer is null, but I don't know why since I'm returning something from the ARM

Comment: You can make str a char* as well. I don't see why you wouldn't.

Comment: @user2255853 If your pointer were null, your C program would have crashed. It sounds more like you're returning a pointer to a `'\0'` char.

Comment: I'm thinking that `cmp r5, #0                  @Check for null character
    add r4, r4, #1              @Add 1 to the length
    bne countLoop` will not do as you plan as the `bne` wants to use the status from the `cmp` instruction, but the `add` instruction also sets the condition codes.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, always check that the returned pointer is NOT NULL`

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, I should have mentioned that I checked the count function I wrote, and that is correct (It correctly returns the length including the null-terminating character)

Comment: do these two instructions increment `a1` and `r6`?  `ldrb r8, [r6], #1   strb r8, [a1], #1`

Comment: when you checked the `length` function, did you keep right on stepping through the code and note what is being passed to the `printf()` function? did you display (in the debugger) what `result` is pointing toward?

Comment: The posted code has a memory leak.  In the C code, before returning, it should call `free( result );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the pointer to the original string to r6 at the start, however afterwards you overwrote r6 in the length function immediately after. I'd suggest to either store it somewhere else too, or use a1 directly in that function call

Answer (score 0):

'the `length` function has some problems.

1. the comparison for exit using wrong results
2. the result does not allow for the trailing NUL character
3. the pointer into the original string not being incremented

Suggest:

```
length:                         @Length function
    mov r4, #1                  @Init counter (always have trailing null)
    mov r5, r6                  @Load ptr to first character

lengthLoop: 
    cmp [r5], #0                @Check for null character
    beq lengthEnd               @done

    add r4, r4, #1              @Add 1 to the length
    add r5, r5, #1              @step to next char in source
    b   lengthLoop              @Loop

lengthEnd:
    mov pc, lr                  @return via link register
```

Comment: caveat: I'm not very familiar with the ARM assembly language, so I'm not sure about the `beq` nor the `b` nor the `ld` as being the correct instructions.